# Joint distribution of $(|Z_1|,\alpha \sum_{i=1}^nZ_i^2)$ when $\alpha \ge 0$ is deterministic and $Z_1,\ldots,Z_n \overset{iid}{\sim} N(0,1)$

Tags: probability, limits, statistics, probability-distributions, independence

Let $Z=(Z_1,\ldots,Z_n)$ be a random vector in $\mathbb R^n$ with iid entries from $N(0,1/n)$ and let $\alpha \ge 0$ be a constant. Define $X := |Z_1|$ and $Y_n:=\alpha \|Z\|^2 := \alpha \sum_{i=1}^nZ_i^2$.

**Question.** What is the joint distribution of $(X,Y_n)$ ? What is the limiting form of this distribution ?

Answer (score 0):

In general, the joint density of $\left(X,Y\right)$ can be written as the product of the conditional density of $Y$ given $X$ and the marginal density of $X$.

Here, let's work with $X^2$ instead of $X$ as it is a bit easier. Then, the marginal distribution of $X^2 = Z^2_1 = \frac{1}{n}Z^2$ for $Z\sim \mathcal{N}\left(0,1\right)$. Then, $Z\sim Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\right)$, also known as a chi-squared distribution, so $X^2 \sim Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{n}{2}\right)$ using the scaling properties of the gamma distribution.

Now, $Y_n$ has the form

$$Y_n = \alpha X^2 + \sum_{i>1} \alpha Z^2_i,$$

where the second term is independent of $X^2$ and has the distribution $Gamma\left(\frac{n-1}{2},\frac{n}{2\alpha}\right)$ since you are adding up $n-1$ independent $Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{n}{2\alpha}\right)$ distributions. This should give you a form for the conditional density of $Y_n$ given $X^2$, and you can look at the product and see if it simplifies to anything useful.